# Can you tell me if my implementation of Insertion Sort is correct? It's working but something feels fishy

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, insertion-sort

It's working but my teacher didn't agreed. Said that my number of iterations will be more. But how??

```
    void InsertionSort(int arr[], int size)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            int flag = 1;
            int val = arr[i];

            for(int j = i-1; j>=0; j--)  //keep swapping till its inserted to its right place
            {
                if(val < arr[j])
                {
                    int temp = arr[j]; 
                    arr[j] = val;
                    arr[i] = temp;
                    i--;  //decrementing i so we keep going left until the condition is false
                    flag = 0;
                }
            if(flag) break; // optimised best case, so inner loop doesn't run for sorted part.
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: did you ask your teacher Why? is a perfomance issue? code style issue?

Comment: Please fix your keyboard, or remember to turn of the caps-lock key. Otherwise you're shouting or yelling at us, which is kind of rude.

Comment: @Vivek Just change your teacher!:)

Comment: Considering the indentation, is the `flag` check in the right place?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ  yes, he told my number of iterations will be more than required. More operation. But idk how??

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will keep that in mind. I'm a newbie.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, flag is placed right I think.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I want to but I can't. He is my college professor. XD

Comment: Just because you have written a program that successfully sorts does not imply that your program successfully implements insertion sort. There will only be a few valid ways to implement insertion sort, so what I would do is compare what I'd written against a known-good insertion sort implementation. Wikipedia probably has one.

Comment: @user4581301 It's insertion sort actually.

Comment: Fixed the comment already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either at least change this code snippet

```
if(val < arr[j])
{
    int temp = arr[j]; 
    arr[j] = val;
    arr[i] = temp;
    i--;  //decrementing i so we keep going left until the condition is false
    flag = 0;
}
```

the following way

```
if(val < arr[j])
{
    int temp = arr[j]; 
    arr[j] = val;
    arr[j+1] = temp;
    flag = 0;
}
```

Or change your teacher.:)

In fact your function works but it is clumsy due to decreasing the variable `i` in the inner loop that leads to repeating iterations of the outer loop for the same value of `i`.

Consider for example an array that starts with elements `{ 2, 1, ... }`. In the first iteration of the outer loop `i` is initialized by `1`. Within the inner loop these two first elements will be swapped and `i` will be decremented and becomes equal tp `0`. Then in the third expression of the outer for loop `i` will be incremented and will be equal to `1` anew. So the loop will repeat its iteration for the same value of the variable `i`.

If to use swapping of adjacent elements in the array as you are doing then the function can be written simpler  without using the variable `flag`.  Pay attention to that the number of elements in the array should have the type `size_t`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void InsertionSort( int arr[], size_t size )
{
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < size; i++ )
    {
        for( size_t j = i; j != 0 && arr[j] < arr[j-1]; j--)
        {
            std::swap( arr[j], arr[j-1] );
        }
    }
}
    
int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    
    InsertionSort( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );
    
    for ( const auto &item : a )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Please explain what's the difference. It's the same thing, right?

Comment: So, what's the issue with my snippet? If so, why is it working? Also (i--) will not decrement i in outer loop, right? Sorry if I'm being dumb but I'm a just a freshman :)

Comment: @Vivek i-- decrements the variable i each time when there are swapped two adjacent elements in the array.  Consider an array that starts with elements { 2, 1,...}. i is set to 1 in the outer loop. After swapping the elements in the inner loop i will be equal to 0. Then in the third expression of the outer loop i is increased. And the next iteration of the outer loop again begins with i equal to 1.